# Include one model's controller functions and view in another models view in ASP.NET MVC?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have a `Model A` and `B`.`Model A` has information for a contact (phone number, email, etc) that `Model B` will have to have as well. I have a model for phones, emails, and addresses that `Model A` is accessing and using via a "master model page" that you can see here:

```
    public class master
{
    public A A { get; set; }
    public phones phones { get; set; }
    public emails emails { get; set; }
    public addresses addresses { get; set; }
}
```

Since `Model A` is using this master model successfully (it creates a new `phone`, `email`, and `address` on the create of a new `Model A`) is there a way that I can just shove my Model A into the create page of my Model B so that I don't have to redo the code that I did to get Model A working? In other words can I use the create view of Model A in the create view of Model B? I hope that makes sense.

**EDIT**

```
    public class A 
    { 
      public int id { get; set;}
      public string name { get; set; }
      public string company { get; set; }
    }

    public class B 
    {
      public string userName
      public string website
    }
```

As you can see B is different from A so it will have to have its own creation field, however, it needs all of the things that A has and all of the things that the controller for A gets (the phone, address, emails) using the master model. I hope that clears things up.

Comment: I think your question is not too clear. Do you want to apply the same logic, properties, etc to model B that A uses? or do you want to include everything from A and B in B?

Comment: Everything from A AND B in B sorry.

Comment: Is B going to have any other unique properties other than A, phones, emails, and addresses?

Comment: Yes It will. Let me Edit...

Comment: @Sofanatic Does the edit help at all?

Comment: @Andy yes, but I think what you should be doing is have `A` inherit from `Master` not have `A` as a property of master, then `B` would be able to inherit from `Master` as well.

Comment: @Sofanatic well I can have B inherit from the master only A is already doing everything that B would have to do. So I want to just inherit A I believe, if that's possible.

Comment: I'm not sure this is what MVC inherently does well, being action-oriented instead of component-oriented. You'd have to restructure this somehow, like maybe create an editor template for all of A.

Comment: @millimoose Im starting to think that it would probably be easier to just go ahead and redo the code the same way I did it for `A`. Oh well.

Comment: Can you explain what models master, A and B are? It's hard to come up with a good class model when name your classes like that.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to have `B` inherit from `A`

Doing this will cause `B` to have both the properties from `A` and `B`

```
public class A 
{ 
  public int id { get; set;}
  public string name { get; set; }
  public string company { get; set; }
  public string SayHello(){ return string.Format("Hello {0}"); }
}

public class B : A
{
  public string userName
  public string website
}
```

you can then do something like

```
var b = new B() { name = "me", company="my company", userName = "me@mycompany.com" };
var greeting = b.SayHello();  // "Hello me"
```